# Maven Spring Boot 2.0.4 - and elastic search 6.2.2 transport jar not in dependency tree

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, elasticsearch

I am writing a SpringBoot 2.0.4 application, (Executable .jar) and I am trying to interface with an elastic search that I do not control. It is 6.2.2

Now I know Spring does not support that,  and that's fine as I am not using any Spring classes, I am interfacing with elastic directly.  However, The problem comes in trying to exclude elastic from spring in my pom.  Here is my pom fragment:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
            <artifactId>transport</artifactId>
        </exclusion>        
    </exclusions>
</dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
        <version>6.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
        <artifactId>transport</artifactId>
        <version>6.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-client</artifactId>
        <version>6.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Now Eclipse has a yellow line under the versions for elasticsearch and transport,  saying that the version is being overridden.  But when I look at the dependency tree,  I see all the elastic jars with the correct version of 6.2.2  -- EXCEPT for transport.  That jar is not there at all. I looked in my executable jar,  and it's definitely not there.  Shockingly, my app throws a class not found error for org/elasticsearch/common/transport/InetSocketTransportAddress

How do I get that jar into my dependencies?

**EDIT**

So I added:

```
<properties>
    <elasticsearch.version>6.2.2</elasticsearch.version>
</properties>
```

to my pom, and overrode the spring version,  but the transport jar is not showing up in my dependency tree!  How do I get this file into my executable jar?